# Cufon... Simple gradient text... isn't working

Tags: javascript, css, text, gradient, cufon

I've been trying for hours to figure out why this won't work... I don't understand, it's not complicated at all, I've stripped it completely clean. Why isn't it working??

I'm trying to turn h1 text into gradient text...

http://jsfiddle.net/aZsUh/1/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />

<title>TITLE</title>

<!-- StyleSheet -->  
<link id="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/cufon-yui.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
Cufon.replace('h1', {
color: '-linear-gradient(#999, 0.45=#666, 0.45=#555, #999)'
});
</script>

</head>

<body>
<h1>Lorem ipsum dolor seiti alpo...</h1>

<script type="text/javascript"> Cufon.now(); </script>
</body>
</html>
```

​

But all I get is plain black text...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a problem with your `Source_Sans_Pro_400.font.js` file. If I add `Vegur.font.js`, the gradient works just fine.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/aZsUh/2/)

Comment: You're right... I don't get it though, I'm generating the file from their website like you're supposed to... http://cufon.shoqolate.com/generate/ . The font is available on Google Fonts, Source Sans normal. Could someone else try generating it for me? It's strange though, the font actually works, it just doesn't apply the gradient... or turn it into cufon.